# Mac not updating

Tags: macbook-pro

So, my app store says it has 8 updates, but every time I go into my App Store nothing loads, not even the main menu. It's frustrating, does it have something to do with space or what? I need help, Ive tried going to different Wi-Fi hotspots but nothing is helping. Please help.

Comment: Does booting in safe mode do anything?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this once before and there are two possible solutions to this:

1. Reset the NVRAM
2. Delete the App Store .plist files

### Reset the NVRAM

While booting your mac, press and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>++<kbd>R</kbd> keys before the gray screen appears.  Don't release until after the second time.

### Delete the .plist files:

Close the App Store

Launch Terminal and type:

```
$ sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
$ sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.storeagent.plist
```

Relaunch the App Store.  It should be working now.

(You will be asked for your password after you type the first one).